# How can I change the AndroidManifest.xml file in Meteor?

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

I need to add a couple activities to my Meteor Cordova Project, namely:

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`
and 
`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`

`App.setPreference` doesn't seem to work for Activities in `mobile-config.js` and `App.setActivity` doesn't seem to exist. 
Docs on `mobile-config.js` are available [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mobileconfigjs).

Is there any way to do this currently?

Comment: Are you using [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/) or the [CLI tools](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html)?

Comment: @sanfor I'm using Meteor's build tool, I'm not sure which it uses (most likely the CLI). They  generate the XML file for you based on the project and start the hosting so that you don't have to think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *AndroidManifest.xml* file can be edited directly and it doesn't seem to get deleted on build.

The file is located in: 
`.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android`

From there the activities can be added directly to the main activity.

I'm still trying to figure out a way to get it to work when pushed to a different server, as the *.meteor* folder isn't included.

Comment: any luck with getting it pushed to a different server?

Comment: Nope, we modify .meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml , and build... nothing changes.  Same error, same line number.

See https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5840#issuecomment-186184372

Comment: Direct editing doesn't work.  The changes are overwritten anytime a build is done.

Answer (score 3):

I am quite sure that what you need to do is specified [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration#advanced-build-customization). Basically what you need to do is

1. Create a file *config.xml* under folder *cordova-build-override/* in your project.
2. Copy the basic *config.xml* generated by creating a new Cordova project.
3. Add

to your *config.xml* this:

```
<application
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
```

4. Make sure you have this

in your *widget* tag for *android* to be available:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

5. Use still the *App.setPreference* etc to set the normal details.

And yes, I know it is quite hacky, but it makes sense as Meteor uses Cordova internally and has only those "normal" *config.xml* options are configurable.

Comment: Hey I tried this, but it didn't work. I posted a solution that seems to work for now. It might have to do with the application tag instead of using an activity tag.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the current (as of 2020) solution to this problem is with a mobile-config.js file in the root of your app directory. 
see meteor docs https://docs.meteor.com/api/mobile-config.html